# Loading and persisting Hazelcast distributed map

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am using **Hazelcast(3.8.1)** as a cache service in my application. After going through the [hazelcast documentation](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8.1/manual/html-single/index.html#using-high-density-memory-store-with-map), I have few doubts related to it:

1. If we use **Write-Behind Persistence**, this being an async calls to its local queue, from which eventually we persist it to a db. 
   **My question is, if all the nodes go down, then will there be a data loss in this scenario?**

*Note: I understand that one copy of the queue is also being maintained in a back up node. But my scenario is when all the node goes down, can we lose data?*

2. Does hazelcast maintain an offline persistence when it goes down and load it when it is started [for all the nodes]?

Appreciate responses.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to **1** is obvious, and is applicable to any in-memory system with asynchronous writes. If **all** nodes in your cluster go down, then yes, there's potential for data loss as your system is only eventually consistent.

For question **2**: Hazelcast is an in-memory cache and therein lie its primary benefits. Writing to or loading from persistent storage should be secondary because it conflicts with some of the main attributes of a caching system (speed, I guess...).

With that said, it allows you to [load from and write to persistent storage](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/Distributed_Data_Structures/Map/Loading_and_Storing_Persistent_Data.html), either synchronously (write-through) or asynchronously (write-behind)

If your main reason for using Hazelcast is replication and partitioning (of persistent, consistent data), then you'd be better off using a NoSql database such as Mongodb. This depends a lot on your usage patters because it may still make sense if you expect far more reads than writes.

If, on the other hand, your main reason for using it is speed, then what you need is to better manage fault-tolerance, which has more to do with your cluster topology (maybe you should have cross-datacenter replication) than with persistence. It's atypical to be concerned with "all nodes dying" in your DC unless you have strong consistency or transaction requirements.

Comment: Appreciate your response.
My scenario is when the cluster is restarted(last node die), will the content in the Hazelcast persist somewhere in the disk?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would lose the data in memory if it is not persisted to the database yet.

OTOH, Hazelcast has [Hot Restart](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/Storage/Hot_Restart_Persistence/Hot_Restart_Types.html) for persistence to disk in Enterprise version. This helps in case of a planned shutdown of whole cluster or a sudden cluster-wide crash, e.g., power outage.

Comment: Thanks for answering, does it ensure no data is lost?

Comment: Yes, fır cases of planned shutdown of whole cluster or a sudden cluster-wide crash. Please note that for partial crashes, in-memory backups (or your Maploader/MapStore) will be leveraged and no hot-restart action will be taken.